# QVector size() returning size zero

Tags: c++, qt, serialization

These 2 functions are my attempt to serialize a QVector. Unfortunally I can't use QDataStream because my boss requires that the implementation is Qt independent and QDataStream prepends a header. So the problem is the vector returned by the function binToVector returns a size equals to 0, but if the elements are printed they are equal to the original vector. Why the size returned is zero if the vector has elements equal to the original? These serialization functions are ok? I cannot use boost neither Qt functions to implement it, only C++;

```
QByteArray vectorToBin(const QVector<qint32> & vec)
{
  QByteArray result;
  foreach(quint32 e, vec) {
    char *src = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&e);
    result.append(src, sizeof(qint32));
  }
  return result;
}

QVector<qint32> binToVector(const QByteArray & bytes) 
{
  int size = sizeof(qint32);
  QVector<qint32> result;
  result.reserve(bytes.count()/size);
  int j=0;
  for(int i=0; i<bytes.count(); i+=size) {
    memcpy(&result[j++], bytes.constData()+i, size);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Your boss wants to... serialize QT data structures... without using QT?

Comment: you are already using QVector so your implementation cannot be independent of Qt. If its a header issue then try forward declaration. Writing what QDataStream has is basically reinventing the wheel. Ask your boss if he would reinvent the wheel :))

Comment: Kind of, @DeadMG. He wants to serialize data that *happens* to be stored in a Qt data structure in the project's current incarnation. He doesn't want to be tied to Qt's serialization format in the event that they decide to use something other than that particular Qt class someday, or if they want other, non-Qt-using projects to be able to consume the same serialized data.

Comment: @Blueskin, the "header" issue isn't about C++ headers and forward declarations. It's about QDataStream writing header information in front of the stored data, like a bitmap header goes in front of pixel data, or a PE header goes in front of an executable.

Comment: When you are serializing the plain int array, you will most probably need to write the size of the array before you write the contents of the array. And this is exactly what the QList serialization does too.

Comment: @DeadMG the data will be serialized in mysql and should be retrieved by other tools in the future.

Comment: `QDataStream` can write your data as is without any header. You have to set the byte order/endianness (that you don't control with your current implementation), and use only basic types (integers, float, chars) with the <</>> operators and write/read raw data with the `QDataStream::writeRawData/readRawData` functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling [`QVector::reserve`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qvector.html#reserve), which allocates memory for the class to use as storage, but doesn't actually change the number of *real* elements in the container. For that, you need [`QVector::resize`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qvector.html#resize). The standard C++ `vector` class works the same way. Reserving space in advance ensures that repeated future calls to `append` don't have to re-allocate the container's storage all the time.